# Cant fix this Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Tags: shortcode

I dont know what i have doing wrong. everything work fine. but i receive a warning in page

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /public_html/wp/xtheme/wp content/themes/tab.php on line 31
```

This is a Shortcode for tab. and this issue  with foreach loop
`$arr = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tab_details',true);
foreach ($arr as $part){....}`

```
function tab_shortcode($atts) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'category' => '',
                    ), $atts, 'tab_shortcode'));
    $q = new WP_Query(
            array('posts_per_page' => '3', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'DESC', 'post_type' => 'post_tab',)
    );
    global $post;
    $list = '
        <ul class="buttons-tab">
        ';

    while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
        $tab_id = get_the_ID();
        $list .= '<li><a href="#' . $tab_id . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
    endwhile;
    $list.= '
                 </ul>
           <div class="tab-content" id="tab">';


    while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
        $tab_id = get_the_ID();

        $arr = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tab_details',true);
        $tab_item = '';

        foreach ($arr as $part) {
            $tab_item .= '<div class="text-icon-left">
                            <span class="iconCircle fa ' . $part['icon'] . '"></span>
                            <div class="text">
                                <p>' . $part['text'] . '</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>';
        }
        $list .= '
            <div class="item tab-pane" data-hash="' . $tab_id . '">' . $tab_item . '</div>';
    endwhile;
    $list.= '
           </div>
        ';
    wp_reset_query();
    return $list;
}

add_shortcode('tab', 'tab_shortcode');
```

Tab displayed fine but this warning showing on page.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the third parameter of `get_post_meta` to true, the function returns a string, [as you can read in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta#Parameters). So:

```
$arr = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tab_details', true);
```

Makes `$arr` be a string and [a string is not a valid argument for a PHP `foreach` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and that is waht the error message says.

Instead, if you set the third parameter to `false` or leave it blank, you will get an array with all values for the spècified meta_key (or an empty array if no values are found):

```
$arr = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tab_details');
//Now $arr is an array
foreach($arr as $part){....}
```